# Python: how to get all the first values row-wise from a 2D numpy array when using a 2D boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, vectorization

I have two large 2D arrays, one with values and the other ones with a mask of "valid" values.

```
vals = np.array([
    [5, 2, 4],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 3, 2],
])

valid = np.array([
    [False, True, True],
    [False, False, True],
    [False, True, True],
])
```

My goal is to get, for each row, the first value when `valid==True`, and obtain a vector of that sort: `[2, 9, 3]`, in the fastest possible way.

I tried applying the mask and querying from it, but it destroys the structure:

```
vals[valid]
> array([2, 4, 9, 3, 2])
```

I tried looping through all the indices, but I am wondering if there is a faster and vectorized way of doing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
vals[np.arange(len(vals)), np.argmax(valid,axis=1)]
```

Or use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis):

```
np.take_along_axis(vals, np.argmax(valid,axis=1)[:,None], axis=1).ravel()
```